# Swift - Share image and video with UIActivityViewController telegram, whatsapp and etc

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share a video and image from a URL using UIActivityViewController.
If I try with an Image I have not problems i try to both i face issues.

```
                guard let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: photo.videoURL! as URL) else {
                    return
                }
                let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
                let docDirectory = paths[0]
                let filePath = "\(docDirectory)/tmpVideo.mov"
                urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
                // File Saved
                let videoLink = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

   let objectsToShare = [imageData,videoLink] //comment!, imageData!, myWebsite!]

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities:nil)

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewController.view
        
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(viewController.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(viewController.view.bounds),0,0)
    }
    viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Anyone give solution to share image and video using UIActivityViewController